# Search for a string in a file and rename multiple files to the results

Tags: awk, grep, xargs

I am attempting to recursively search through a list of files and if the file contains a string, rename the file to the grep results of said string.

The sample files contain a the following content:

```
file1   
foo bar1

file2
foo bar2

file3
foo bar3

file4
foo bar4

file5
foo bar5
```

grep + awk return the results that I need:

```
$ grep -r "^foo" . | awk '{print $2}'
bar1
bar2
bar3
bar4
bar5
```

I'm stuck at passing these results to a mv command.

```
$ grep -r "^foo" . | awk '{print $2}' | xargs -I{} mv {} .
mv: cannot stat 'bar1': No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat 'bar2': No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat 'bar3': No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat 'bar4': No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat 'bar5': No such file or directory
```

Thanks in advance. Gnu/BSD Grep both have the same results.

Answer (score 2):

I would use a shell for-loop:

```sh
for match in "$(grep -ro '^foo.*')";do
    echo mv "${match%:*}" "${match#*:}"
done
```

This will iterate all the matching `file:matching-substring` and use the `%` and `#` string operators to delete everything up to, resp. everything after, and including `:`.

Note that if you really want to match the whole line as opposed to just the substring that matches the pattern, use

```
for match in $(grep -r '^foo');do
```

Make sure to double-quote since matches and/or filenames could contain spaces.

If you want to match by one pattern but rename the file to the second word in the matching line:

```
for match in "$(grep -ro '^foo.*')";do
    fname=$("echo ${match#*:}|awk '{print $2}'")
    echo mv "${match%:*}" "$fname"
done
```

Comment: If I'm going to pipe the results of grep to awk to return the second record, would i modify it like so:  `for match in "$(grep -ro '^foo' . | awk '{print $2}')";do
    echo mv "${match%:*}" "${match#*:}";
done`

Comment: What do you mean with "the second record"? If you mean the second match (i.e. the second line where the grep pattern matched), you don't need a loop, just pipe the grep call to `sed -n '2p'`.

Comment: If you mean to rename by the second word, see the last variant in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you are trying to accomplish using perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;

my $dir = "/path/to/directory";
chdir $dir or die "Cannot open $dir!";

my @files = grep { -f } glob("*");

foreach my $file(@files) {
  open F1, "<", $file or die "Cannot open file $file! $!\n";
  while ( <F1> ){
    chomp;
    my @strings = split(' ');
    if($strings[1] =~ /bar/){
      system("/bin/mv $file $strings[1]");
    }
  }
  close(F1);
}
```

Comment: Will this be recursive?

Comment: No, it will only look for files in $dir. You could extend the program to recurse, but if you have a lot of files in subdirectories you could use [http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Find.html] to populate @files

Answer (score 0):

`find . -type f -exec egrep -il '^foo' {} \; | sort | while IFS='' read -r line; do mv -n "$line" "$(dirname "$line")"'/'"$(egrep -i '^foo' "$line" | awk '{ print $2 }')"; done`